# Oracle SQL - Running a query multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select '2012-Nov-01' As "Week_Of",
count(player_id) as cohort_size ,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 0 
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_0_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 1 
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_1_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 2
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_2_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 3
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_3_Ret
from player
where trunc(create_dtime) > To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd')-7
and trunc(create_dtime) <= To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
and world_flag != '1'
Which outputs:

Week_Of       Cohort_size    Day_0_Ret    Day_1 Ret    Day_2_Ret    Day_3_Ret
2012-Nov-01    2426           2426        1412         1349          1316
```

I want to be able to run this query for multiple sets of dates, so that my output would look something like:

```
Week_Of       Cohort_size    Day_0_Ret    Day_1 Ret    Day_2_Ret    Day_3_Ret
2012-Nov-01    2426           2426        1412         1349          1316
2012-Nov-08    5106           2458        1945         1379          1248
2012-Nov-15    3580           1476        1412         1349          1146
```

Instead of having the re run the query everytime for a specific week of. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're willing to manually enter these dates then you can `UNION` then together and then `INNER JOIN` the result with your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query changes your logic to a `group by` rather than a where:

```
select to_char(max(create_dtime), 'yyyy-mm-dd') As "Week_Of",
       count(player_id) as cohort_size ,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 0 
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_0_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 1 
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_1_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 2
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_2_Ret,
count(case 
    when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 3
    then player_id 
  end) as Day_3_Ret
from player
where trunc(create_dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd') - 6
and world_flag != '1'
group by trunc((trunc(create_dtime) - (To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd') -  6))/7)
order by 1
```

It chooses the last available date to describe the week....

Comment: This doesn't seem to work 1 for 1. I'm not exactly sure what's missing but, when I run this , the week of 2012-Nov-01 out put day_0_ret of 2784 instead of 2426, and so on down the line.

Comment: @Stuave . . . There was an "off-by-one" error on the weeks.  I consider "week-of" to be the beginning date, rather than the end date.  I noticed that your original query subtracts 7 days before Nov 1, rather than adds them.  I fixed the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I apologize as I'm not quite sure I follow. I was hoping to get your query to tie out to my original query for the "Week of Nov 1" as I had defined it. I'm not sure I follow the subtraction of 6 at the bottom. Is there anyway to suggest a way to tie out to my original query? Thank you!

Comment: @stuave . . . `>= To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd') - 6` is the same as `> To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd') - 7`.  They should be counting the weeks from 6 days before that date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff perhaps it is the group by trunc((trunc(create_dtime) - To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd') -  6)/7)? because when i run the query instead of week of (or week end as it should be titled) 2012-11-01, it becomes 2012-10-31.

Comment: @Stuave . . . Yes, I think there should be parentheses.